# `find_one` does not give ObjectId in proper format

Tags: mongodb, rust

As the title states, here is the following code.

```rust
    let users_coll = db
        .database("foo")
        .collection::<bson::oid::ObjectId>("users");
    let user_id = users_coll
        .find_one(
            doc! { "email": &account.email },
            mongodb::options::FindOneOptions::builder()
                .projection(doc! { "_id": 1i32 })
                .build(),
        )
        .await?
        .unwrap();
```

But it fails at `?` operator with the following `mongodb::error::Error`,

```
Error { kind: BsonDeserialization(DeserializationError { message: "expected map containing extended-JSON formatted ObjectId, instead found { \"_id\": ObjectId(\"62af199df4a16d3ea6056536\") }" }), labels: {}, wire_version: None, source: None }
```

And it is right. Given ObjectId should be in this format,

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "62af199df4a16d3ea6056536"
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to handle this. Any help is appreciated.

Have a good day!

Comment: You're stating that the return value is `ObjectID`, but in fact it is an object of the shape `{_id: ObjectId}`. I don't know how to fix it (hence the comment and not an answer), but the error must be here.

Comment: According to [Collection](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/struct.Collection.html) documentation.

"A `Collection` can be parameterized with any type that implements the `Serialize` and `Deserialize` traits from the `serde` crate."
Since `ObjectId` also implements `Serialize` and `Deserialize` this should not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, but it's not _actually stored_ in the collection you're querying. And, I'm afraid, it can't be stored there, since document is always an object, and `ObjectId` is, from the MongoDB's perspective, a primitive, not an object.

Answer (score 2):

Your `users` collection isn't a collection of `ObjectId`s, it's actually a collection of documents which each contain an `ObjectId`. To let Rust know what to do with those, you should create a struct which represents the document, or at least the parts which you care about getting back from your query, and tell your collection to de-serialize into that struct:

```rust
use mongodb::bson::oid::ObjectId;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, Default, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct User {
    _id: ObjectId,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let users_coll = db
        .database("foo")
        .collection::<User>("users");

    let user_id: ObjectId = users_coll
        .find_one(
            doc! { "email": &account.email },
            mongodb::options::FindOneOptions::builder()
                .projection(doc! { "_id": 1i32 })
                .build(),
        )
        .await?
        .unwrap()
        ._id;
}
```

By default, the BSON fields have to match the struct fields exactly (`_id` in this case), but I'm pretty sure `serde` has a way to change that if you don't like the leading underscore.